# Cannot output all rows of array in a database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

**Problem:** Can only output one field from each array

```
 <?php
    error_reporting(0);
    session_start();
    include('connect.php');
    ob_start();

    $category = array(
        "dates" => array(),
        "paragraphs" => array(),
        "titles" => array()
    );

    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tips")){
        if($result->num_rows){
            while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            //printf ("%s %s %s\n",$row["date"], $row["title"], $row["paragraph"]); 
            $dates= array($row["date"]);
            $titles = array($row["title"]);
            $paragraphs = array($row["paragraph"]);
            }
            }
            $result->free();
        }

    ?>
```

I want the last in the array to be displayed first so I'm using this

```
<?php echo $titles[count($titles)-1]?>
```

I think the problem is with my loop, I think its reassigning the array each time it loops round

Comment: Each iteration of while creates a new array in your vars, which first position stores current row data iteration. It overwrites the last one each time, try not `$data = array($row['data'])` but `$data[] = $row['data']`. This way you push the values of each iteration into a new index of the array.

Comment: Works perfectly Alan, thank you very much. Write it as the answer and ill accept

Comment: Your code assumes that`$titles` is an array, when it is not.

Comment: Do you really need to `SELECT` all items from your table? why not just get the last one you need?

Comment: I don't need to select all indeed, I shall use LIMIT in my select statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each iteration of `while` creates a new array in your vars, which first position stores current row data iteration.

It overwrites the last one each time, try not `$data = array($row['data'])` but `$data[] = $row['data']`.

This way you push the values of each iteration into a new index of the array.

Answer (score 1):

you are not adding values to the `$category` array properly :

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   $category['dates'][] = $row["date"];
   $category['titles'][] = $row["title"];
   $category['paragraphs'][] = $row["paragraph"];
}
```

as it is now, with `$dates= array($row["date"])` etc, you just assign the values to the same (never declared) `$dates` variable over and over.

Comment: yes and no.. this will create arrays for each column set rather than per each row set.

Comment: @CodeGodie, `$category['titles']` is an array, `$category['titles'][] = $row["title"]` will add new elements to that array; by that OP can display the last item with `echo $category['titles'][count($category['titles'])-1]`, I _guess_ that he have forgotten his `$category` declaration too :)